# Como remover palavras indesejadas de um texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando remover as palavras indesejadas de um texto qualquer, mas ele retira de outras palavras. Por exemplo:

```
remover_palavras = ["a", "e", "o"]
```

O programa devolve: btt (batata), mns (menos)

O que fazer?

Comment: Tem como detalhar melhor seu problema? Você quer remover as letras "a", "e" e "o" apenas quando estão sozinhas? Aliás, edite a pergunta e adicione o seu código.

Comment: [Cuidado com esse tipo de substituição](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/2302/the-clbuttic-mistake), ele não tem muita abundaracidade.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, sim quando estão sozinhas. Quero que meu programa ingore as stopWords, como: de, se, ele, você, aquele, etc.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de uma entrada e como você quer na saída?

Answer (score 6):

Se for uma brincadeira simples, você pode criar um algoritmo que faça o seguinte:

1. Cria uma lista com as palavras a serem removidas do texto.
2. Cria uma lista (`lista_frase`) onde cada elemento da lista é uma palavra da sua frase original.
3. Cria uma segunda lista (`result`), selecionando os itens da primeira lista (`lista_frase`) que não estejam na lista de palavras excluídas (`remover_palavras`).
4. Junta todos os elementos da lista resultante separando-os por um espaço.

Exemplo de código:

```
frase = 'Oi, eu sou Goku e estou indo para a minha casa'

remover_palavras  = ['a', 'e']
lista_frase = frase.split()

result = [palavra for palavra in lista_frase if palavra.lower() not in remover_palavras]

retorno = ' '.join(result)
print(retorno)
```

A saída será

> Oi, eu sou Goku estou indo para minha casa

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso217042)

Answer (score 0):

Pra mim a melhor forma seria com Regular Expressions:

```
import re

text = 'Oi, eu sou Goku e estou indo para a minha casa'
palavras = ['a','e']

for i in palavras:
    text = re.sub(r'\s'+i+'([\s,\.])',r'\1',text) 

print(text)
```

Acho interessante que caso haja alguma pontuação que ela seja mantida, mas dai vai do seu interesse.

Answer (score -1):

Sou iniciante em Python, mas função que resolve o seu problema.

### Função

```
def remover_palavra(palavra, remover):
    remover_tamanho = len(remover)
    palavra_tamanho = len(palavra)
    while True:
        remover_posicao = palavra.find(remover)
        if remover_posicao != -1:
            palavra_inicio = palavra[0:remover_posicao]
            palavra_fim = palavra[remover_posicao+remover_tamanho:palavra_tamanho]
            palavra = palavra_inicio + palavra_fim
        else:
            break
    return palavra
```

### Teste:

```
palavras = ["batata", "menos"]
palavras_para_remover = ["a", "e", "o"]
for palavra in palavras:
    resultado = palavra;
    for remover in palavras_para_remover:
        resultado = remover_palavra(resultado, remover)
    print(resultado)
```

### Saída:

```
btt
mns
```

Comment: Essa é exatamente o resultado que não é esperado. Veja que você não removeu palavras, mas sim as letras da palavras. Não é isso o pedido. Se a frase for "a batata", a saída deverá ser apenas "batata", não "btt".

Comment: Acho que entendi  o que você quis dizer. Realmente não tinha entendido a pergunta. Mas o código chega a funcionar (como disse estou iniciando com python agora). Usando como variáveis: "palavras = ["a batata"]palavras_para_remover = ["a "]" funciona, mas realmente o ideal é o código verificar espaços entre as palavras...

Comment: Veja a solução do jbueno acima. Ela é bem simples e faz o que se pede. Será útil estudá-la.